# How to implement a Canary DAG in Airflow for health checks of other jobs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, pipeline, airflow-scheduler

My team has multiple airflow jobs. The job which run frequently are getting scheduled and running properly, But the jobs which are run rarely often are not scheduled and are skipped.

I would mainly like to create a health checking DAG to be alerted when my jobs are not scheduled and not run.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, `Canary Dag`

- is not supposed to do any *real work*
- it is just a dummy-dag running to testify uptime of Airflow scheduler

---

With above points in mind

- I think `DummyOperator` (do nothing, but merely execution of task is enough to give us a clue), `PythonOperator` (`print` something) & `BashOperator` (`echo` something) are good contenders for tasks that must comprise Canary Dag
- [robinhood guys](https://github.com/robinhood/airflow-prometheus-exporter#requirements) say they write `..tasks which perform very simple actions such as establishing database connections..`

Comment: I get this point, but I am not clear on the point on what happens if that dag itself does not run? I may sound silly, but if there is a problem with the scheduler and the canary dag itself fails, how do we notify the engineers that it has failed?

Comment: **[1]** if the Canary DAG does dummy stuff in first alternative above (no-op, echo statements), then it is never expected to fail. Thus, the failure of Canary Dag would imply that our Canary Dag (tasks) itself was not correct, and we will be able to modify it accordingly so that it no longer remains *failure-prone* (but not *failure-proof*) **[2]** Given that it is meant to indicate scheduler heartbeat only, even failure of Canary Dag *could* be acceptable (initial few days): since both failure & success would indicate heartbeat (but no-status / non-completion would raise a red-flag)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get your point, I can keep a job which can monitor the heartbeat, and raise an alarm based on that, can you provide any idea wrt how to restart a gcp composer scheduler from a cron?