# How to check airflow scheduler healthy and status?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

i have configured apache-airflow with postgreSSQL database and in my airflow i have running 1 dag, now its running successfully but if scheduler have any issue means how i get that and what is the way to check that, kindly give some idea and solution.

Answer (score 7):

- Airflow exposes [`/health` endpoint](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/check-health.html) for this purpose
- Also do check [`REST API` reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/rest-api-ref.html), it has many useful endpoints for several common day-to-day stuff like [triggering a DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/rest-api-ref.html#endpoints) or returning the [latest runs of DAGs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/rest-api-ref.html#get--api-experimental-latest_runs)

---

**UPDATE-1**

Apparently just because `scheduler` is running, doesn't necessarily mean that it will actually trigger a DAG; for e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62684593/3679900)

- you can think of it like there could be internal bugs / interesting corrupt internal states of Airflow that may cause it to not trigger DAGs
- Thus people have gone a step ahead and they schedule a [`canary DAG`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58178143/3679900) (a dummy DAG which does nothing but runs every few minutes). Then by monitoring metrics (think [`prometheus`](https://github.com/robinhood/airflow-prometheus-exporter)) of canary DAG, they can reliably affirm if Airflow scheduler is working as expected or not.

Comment: How do we debug further from here?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with my Airflow scheduler container going unhealthy, causing no jobs to run without any warning that they had stopped.

I wrote this bash script on the host system to email me if the container becomes unhealthy:

```
healthy=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Health.Status}}' YOUR-CONTAINERS-NAME)

# Check if healthy
if [[ $healthy != "healthy" ]]; then
  SERVER="smtpmail.company.com"
  FROM="ITAlerts@company.com"
  TO="You@company.com"
  SUBJ="Airflow scheduler container is unhealthy"
  MESSAGE="Please investigate as Airflow jobs may not be running."
  CHARSET="utf-8"
  sendemail -f $FROM -t $TO -u $SUBJ -s $SERVER -m $MESSAGE -v -o message-charset=$CHARSET
fi
```

Change container name and email parameter values as needed.  This uses the `sendemail` package, on Ubuntu you can install it with `sudo apt-get install sendemail`.

Then save this as `airflow_health_monitor.sh` and add a line to cron (with `crontab -e`) like this to tell it to run every six hours:

`0 */6 * * * ~/airflow_health_monitor.sh`